# Android notification is not opening activity

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I have a simple activity where I create a notification. When notification is clicked, it should open another activity. However, the Resualt activity doesn't start. Where did I make a mistake? Thank's for any help.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button btnShow, btnClear;
NotificationManager manager;
Notification myNotication;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button notif = (Button) findViewById(R.id.notif);
    manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notif.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showNotif("09364415580", "hello!", getApplication());
        }
    });

}
public void showNotif(String from, String body , Context con) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , Resualt.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 1, intent, 0);

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    builder.setAutoCancel(false);
    builder.setTicker(body);
    builder.setContentTitle(from);
    builder.setContentText(body);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.searc);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setOngoing(true);
  //  builder.setSubText("This is subtext...");   //API level 16
    builder.setNumber(100);
    builder.build();

    myNotication = builder.getNotification();
    manager.notify(11, myNotication);

}
```

ResualtActivity:

```
public class Resualt extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.resualt);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hi ! hi ! hi ! " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix this line:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this);
```

then change this:

```
manager.notify(11, builder.build());
```

and delete these lines

```
builder.build();

myNotication = builder.getNotification();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your Code locally and it seems that you've forgotten to declare your Resualt Activity in your AndroidManifest.xml. Try adding a

```
<activity android:name=".Resualt">
</activity>
```

inside your application tag.